# Merge two arrays in alternating sequence in Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have two arrays `A` and `B`, both of which contain lots of elemets and look like this:

```
var A = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
var B = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

Now I want an array `C` that "merges" `A` and `B` by concatenating them in alternating sequence so that

```
C = ["A", 1, "B", 2, "C", 3, "D", 4]
```

I tried this:

```
for (var i = 0; p < 3; i++) {
    C = A[i].concat(B[i])
}
```

But this results in `C = "D4"`.

How can I achieve that I merge two arrays in by alternately choosing one element of each array?

Comment: I have done a jsperf to compare possible solutions: http://jsperf.com/merge-two-arrays-in-alternating-sequence

Comment: That is awesome. Thank you for your effort and time with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var l = A.length + B.length,
    C = Array(l);
for(var i=0; i<l; ++i)
    C[i] = (i%2 ? B : A)[i/2|0];
```

Basically, it fills `C` with items from `A` or `B` depending on if `i` is even or odd.

Note I used `i/2|0` as a shortcut, but it will only work i `l` is strictly less than 2<sup>31</sup>. If you want to be safe, use `Math.floor(i/2)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) together for this:

```js
var A = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
var B = [1, 2, 3, 4];

var result = A.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev.concat(curr, B[prev.length / 2]);
}, []);

alert(result);
```

Or simply `for` or `forEach` loop:

```
var result = [];
A.forEach(function(el, i) {
    result.push(el, B[i]);
});
```

will produce the same result.

Answer (score 2):

```
var C = [];
for (var i = 0; p < 3; i++) {
  C.push(A[i]);
  C.push(B[i]);
}
```