# Merge multiple arrays based on their index using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to merge two arrays into a single array.  I have code but it is not working as expected-- it is merging them one after another, but I need to interlock the values.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    var array2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
    var newArray = $.merge(array1, array2);
    $("#result").html(newArray);
    //the result its 1234absd
    //ineed result like 1a,2b,3c,4d
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what if both arrays are of different length?

Comment: if you need to merge more than 2 arrays in this way, i've created a function in my answer below

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `Array#map` in plain javascript.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var array2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

var newArray = array1.map((e, i) => e + array2[i]);
console.log(newArray);
```

If you use map on array1 then first parameter is current value of array1 in loop and the second parameter is index of that element in array. So you can match current element in array1 with elements from other arrays with the same index using index.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var array2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
var array3 = ["f", "d", "s", "a"];

var newArray = array1.map(function(value, index) {
  return value + array2[index] + array3[index];
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: its work good thank you bur can you please explain the function .                and i.e i need 3 or 4 arrays to margin all together with yhis function and again thank you very match.

Comment: Do all arrays have the same length?

Comment: this solution is fixed to the count of arrays, which is not as versatile as it could be.

Answer (score 11):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for an arbitrary count of arrays with same length.

```js
var a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    a2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    a3 = [9, 8, 7, 6],
    a4 = ["z", "y", "x", "w"],
    result = [a1, a2, a3, a4].reduce((a, b) => a.map((v, i) => v + b[i]));

console.log(result);
```

ES5

```js
var a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    a2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    a3 = [9, 8, 7, 6],
    a4 = ["z", "y", "x", "w"],
    result = [a1, a2, a3, a4].reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a.map(function (v, i) {
            return v + b[i];
        });
    });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just a little variation note, to merge by index in an array multiple, to create an **associative array** of values.

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4],
      b = [34, 54, 54, 43]

console.log(
  a.map((e,i) => [e,b[i]])
)
```

---

Then later, to search for the **closest match** from a given value.
On this example, searching for the best associated value for `3.7`:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4],
      b = [34, 54, 54, 43],
      c = a.map((e,i) => [e,b[i]]),
      search = 3.7,
      temp = [];
      
c.forEach(function(e){
  temp.push(e[0])
})

const seek = temp.reduce((m, n) => (Math.abs(n-search) < Math.abs(m-search) ? n : m))

const index = c.findIndex((s) => s.indexOf(seek) !== -1)
console.log(c[index][1])
```

This is not exactly how behave **an object**.

For example, identical *index* entries aren't merged but are holding their associated values in a new entry (duplicate index), we can roll Math from the *index*, and create transformation matrix. We can use any column as index and search both way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567771/merge-two-arrays-in-alternating-sequence-in-jquery/26567825#26567825)):

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var array2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
var newArray = array1.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return prev.concat(curr, array2[prev.length / 2]);
}, []);
$("#result").html(newArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well actually JavaScript lacks a `.zip()` functor which would be very handy for exactly what you are trying to do. Lets invent it;

```js
Array.prototype.zip = function(a){
 return this.map((e,i) => typeof e === "object" || typeof a[i] === "object" ? [e,a[i]] : e+a[i]);
};

var arrays = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
              ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
              [9, 8, 7, 6],
              ["z", "y", "x", "w"],
              [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
             ],
result = arrays.reduce((p,c) => p.zip(c));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs to merge any number of arrays (with fixed length) in the way mentioned above in the post, following function will be useful

```js
console.clear();
var array1 = ["a1", "b1", "c1", "d1"];
var array2 = ["a2", "b2", "c2", "d2"];
var array3 = ["a3", "b3", "c3", "d3"];
var array4 = ["a4", "b4", "c4", "d4"];

function mergeElementsAtIndex(one_or_more_arrays){
    const total_arr = arguments.length;
    newArray = arguments[0].map((v, k) => {
   var temp_val = v;
        for(var i=1; i < total_arr; i++){
         temp_val += arguments[i][k];
        }
        return temp_val;
    });
    return newArray;
}
merged_array = mergeElementsAtIndex(array1, array2, array3, array4);
console.log(merged_array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var array2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
var array3 = ["f", "d", "s", "a"];

var newArray = array1.map(function(value, index) {
  return value + array2[index] + array3[index];
});
console.log(newArray);
```